# Using netcat / ncat to test the Hole Punching paradigm / technique

Tags: networking, netcat

Being in need to revalidate rationale behind internal workings of protocols of my own I decided to play around with netcat to simulate what's to be going on under the hood.

**The Aim**
Is to simulate the paradigm of Hole Punching - a popular technique for traversal of NATs. In my test-bet there's one client behind NAT, and one server - which is wide open to the Internet.

I'm having trouble..

**FIRST PART of the exercise:;**

I listen with (server-side):

```
 netcat -v -u -l -p 492
```

I connect with  (from behind of a NAT)

```
ncat -u -p 501 REMOTE_PORT 492
```

The hole seemingly gets punched (as I can send data from the server) after the **session** (note that UDP is a state-less, connection-less protocol) has been established (data arrived at server). I test by simply typing in the server-side terminal. but I'm having two MAJOR issues probably with netcat itself:

- why would netcat BIND (implicitly through invocation of CONNECT) a server socket to the first connected client **is BEYOND me** - in an utility which is supposed to be **(?)** a swis-army-kinfe for net-testing.
- In the midst of things I spawned yet another terminal and was hoping to generate yet another datagram to 501 destined to the client node. No luck. Thought that was because netcat binds the server socket to 501 and maybe it doesn't know how to use SO_REUSEADDRESS but nope. After having killed the server, I'm still unable to target the hole.

Also, **SECOND PART of the exercise:;**

- When I initiate an outgoing session from client behind NAT through  `ncat -u -p 501 REMOTE_PORT 492` the NATs seem to allow the datagrams through after say >3 datagrams have been dispatched (also spotted in the First Part of the exercise). If less datagrams, these do not arrive at destination at all. But, if such a condition is met, I can respond at the server side (which is not behind a NAT) by typing in netcat's terminal on the server side.

But then, I wanted to reproduce the situation by simply having:

- the client behind NAT, dispatch datagrams with say:
  ncat -u -p 4033 REMOTE_HOST 447

I expect the above to punch a hole at the NAT so that it would let datagrams through from REMOTE_HOST when datagrams destined for port 4033. After all, only NATs are supposed to see the datagrams fly by, the actual server-side code should be of no significance at all.

- so after having fired the client part multiple times (so to simulate the requirement I spotted earlier of multiple datagrams for NAT rules to be created) I then try, at server side, to send datagrams the other way around through an invocation of :`netcat -u  -p 447 NAT_IP 4033` - hoping for these to get through the 'hole'.

without lock; I've tripple checked that IP addresses to be correct NAT_IP is exactly the same as reported by server side running in verbose mode in First Part of the exercise.

**All the time I keep watching traffic with Wireshark over at the client side; just to make sure that neither netcat nor ncat are trying to play any unexpected tricks on me(like binding to the first client or whatever).**

In theory I believe the second exercise should produce the exact same result; It does not;

I have verified that no ICMP datagrams are flowing by,i.e. due to closed-ports etc that could affect decision making of NATs involved etc.

Update: I went ahead in an attempt to verify this further, the different results I'm getting Between Case 1 and Case 2.
[image]

Above is a wireshark log as seen by client during the hole-punching stage. The pink horizonal line delimits case 1 (below) and case 2 (above) ... pretty same if you ask me. Still, in the first case  I can detect datagrams making their way from hotspot to client (behind NAT) as seen below:
[image]

The commands used for the above are:

```
ncat -u -p 4433 103.102.238.182 443 <- for client side
netcat -v -u -l -p 443 <- server side
```

The hole gets punched as you can see two way communication above.

Now, let's try case 2, in which there's no netcat running on the server (yet no ICMP responses generated).

First lets execute the client command:

```
ncat -u -p 4433 103.102.238.182 443 <- for client side
```

generate few datagrams by typing and pressing enter few times, so NATs see the very same thing.
[image]
and then on server side I'm expecting to be able to send UDP datagram through the punched hole by using the command below:

```
netcat -u 37.30.0.204 4433
```

notice that ports are set for exact match with the previous exercise.

[image]

**Result:** datagrams from server side never make their way onto the computer behind the NAT even though the communication pattern during the hole-punching stage looks exactly the same.

The wireshark filter that I use:
[image]

**Update 3:**
To be as much explicit as possibly one can be. If we use method 1 to hole-punch the communication channel. And in a few seconds just KILL the server netcat session (CTRL+C) and the very instant try to send a datagram to client through  `netcat -u 37.30.0.204 4433` - this wouldn't work.

**Update 4.** Having spent 5+ years as a reverse engineer I have trouble letting things go.

so, I use:

```
nping  -c 150 --udp -p 448 -g 445 103.102.238.182 --data-length 10 --ttl 128 --rate 5
```

to punch a hole within the router. seemingly with success **BUT** I cannot verify this through invocation of

```
nping --udp -p 445 -g 444  37.30.0.204 --data-length 15 --ttl 48 (from client side).
```

The 37.30.0.204 address is correct as it's reported on server side when in verbose mode - when datagrams reach it from client.

I've even set the TTL values to mimic those from Exercise 1.

I can verify success by spawning ncat server on server side AND replying from there (by typing in terminal) - the packets DO arrive when hole is being punched through nping. (the windows machine screams with ICMP host unreachable datagrams, yeah.. who ever cared about security on windows..shutting down the netcat on server side.. BUT.. the packet do get past the NAT).
**Update 5:**
I've nailed it. Will describe in a short while as an answer to this 'quesiton'.

Comment: Considering [`nc`-`netcat`-`ncat` possible confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368160/108618) and to make things clearer, I'm asking: you listen with `netcat`, but you connect with `ncat`; right?

Comment: nc and netcat are aliases for same utility; I'm using ncat together with netcat, any notable differences in functions I tried to use?

Comment: I don't know, but if someone wants to replicate your results then he or she will appreciate knowing for sure what tools you used. I would expect the same tool in the two commands, hence the question. OK, so you used two separate tools, nothing wrong with this; now we know for sure. The fact there are two main implementations of `nc`/`netcat` does not help (there may be nuances). Can you tell us what `netcat` do you use (OpenBSD or the other)? The first line of the output of `netcat -h` may help.

Comment: Debian implementation of netcat (not OpenBSD), windows machine is behind nat thus NCAT. Appreciate your interest.

Comment: in regards to the server-side netcat sending on the same port it listens on, netcat only cares about local and remote port, with nothing built in for separate send/receive. To test that, just have your server-netcat pass output to a second "client" netcat instance, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797025/7411885 for example

Comment: @Cpt.Whale that turned out to be obvious as there's a single param. anyway I've removed that part as that was wrong-thinking on my part. The behavior is expected.

Answer (score 0):

OK folks all of a sudden, while playing around with `nping`, I've noticed this line, on server side, when UDP-pinging the client-node at the same time, as the client was pinging the server:
[image]

My eyes wide open.. **:3241** and of course, the NAT kept changing/translating source ports.

**In Exercise 1** the netcat server was very much aware of the source port, just by looking at data-structure representing the incoming datagrams.

**In Exercise 2** though, I had no idea that NAT changed the source port number and I insisted on targeting the source port number as reported on client-side (which had no chance to work).

Anyway, here are the nping commands that successfully carry our hole-punching and ascertain a 2-way communication channel in the A priori described scenario:

- **client side (hole punching)**:

  ```
  nping  -c 150 --udp -p 448 -g 445 103.102.238.182 --data-length 10 --ttl 128 --rate 5
  ```
- **server side (testing the session / established path):**

  ```
  nping --udp -p 32421 -g 448 37.30.0.204 --data-length 15 --ttl 48
  ```

Till the next time, fellas.

In Wireshark, at client-side one can see the expected target port which showcases that NAT does destination-address-translation, as well - when packets are flowing from server to the client.